# Degree of a torsion-free subsheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves, holomorphic-bundles

Suppose that $R$ is a torsion-free subsheaf (of positive rank) in another torsion-free sheaf $S$, on a smooth complex projective variety $X$.

If $S$ is (slope) semistable, is it true that the degree of $R$ is always less than or equal to that of $S$?  If so, why?

This is not a question about how to define the degree, but if you believe the method of definition affects the answer, then please explain.

Also, I prefer not to make assumptions about the dimension of $X$.

A reference to a specific result in a book or paper would be appreciated in lieu of an explanation (but only if you are sure about the reference and the specificity).

(**Note:** The first sentence of Krish's answer below refers to an earlier version of the question, in which stability was not required.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for vector bundles this is not true. Take $X = \mathbb{P}^1, S = \mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1), R = \mathcal{O}(1).$

Note that, we always have the following relation deg$(R) +$ deg$(S/R) =$ deg$(S)$, where degree is defined with respect to a fixed ample divisor on $X.$ So deg$(R) \leq$ deg$(S) \Leftrightarrow$ deg$(S/R) \geq 0.$ Even if deg$(S) \geq 0,$ in general it can happen that deg$(S/R) < 0$ (see the above example).

But if $S$ is semi-stable, then it is true that deg$(R) \leq$ deg$(S)$, provided deg$(S) \geq 0$. If deg$ (S ) < 0$, then it is not true in general. Take $ X = \mathbb {P}^n, n \geq 1$ and consider the following exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathcal {O}(-1) \rightarrow \mathcal {O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal {O}(-1) \rightarrow \mathcal {O}(-1) \rightarrow 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot.  When I posed the question, I only had stable examples in my mind as a reference point, even though I said I wasn't making such assumptions.  I will edit the question appropriately!

Comment: Question edit done, with semistability as an assumption.  Just to add to the last line of your very good answer, the slope semistability of $S$ requires $\deg(R)/\mbox{rank}(R)\leq\deg(S)/\mbox{rank}(S)$, which means $\deg(R)\leq\deg(S)\cdot(\mbox{rank}(R)/\mbox{rank}(S))$.  We have $\mbox{rank}(R)/\mbox{rank}(S)<1$, from which the required result follows.

Comment: @Bundles: You need to consider the case rank$R =$ rank $S$ also.

Comment: That's true, but I also think the conclusion is false in general, *even* under the assumption of semistability.  (I was just about to add that my arguments with the inequalities in my last comment only yields $\deg(R)\leq\deg(S)$ when $\deg(S)\geq0$.)

Comment: For example, suppose that $S$ is a rank $4$ stable bundle of degree $-3$ containing a rank $2$ sub-bundle $R$ of degree $-2$.  The slope of $R$ is $-1$ and is strictly less than the slope of $S$, which is $-3/4$. But the degree of $R$ exceeds that of $S$.

Comment: Krish: can you see a reason why a stable bundle fitting the description in my previous comment cannot exist?  Bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$ do not count since they are at best semistable and even then, must split as copies of line bundles all of the *same* degree.  So the bundle, if it exists, will need to live on a positive-genus curve.